# Amazon DocumentDB error "Aggregation stage not supported: '$collStats'"

Tags: aws-documentdb, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

I want to check compression ratio of my collection in Amazon DocumentDB, but when I run commands proposed in the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/doc-compression.html :
`db.printCollectionStats()` or `db.collection.stats()`

I get an error:

```
{ ok: 0, errmsg: "Aggregation stage not supported: '$collStats'" }
```

My cluster is using Engine version `docdb 5.0.0`.

I tried to run above commands from `mongosh` v 2.00 and NodeJS driver (`mongodb` v6.0.0) and got the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Supported MongoDB APIs, Operations, and Data Types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html) link provided in ray's answer I found out that `$collStats` aggregation is not supported, but [`collStats`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/collStats/) command is.

mongosh and Node driver are using `$collStats` aggregation under the hood so it does not work with DocumentDB.

Instead, one need to invoke `collStats` command directly on db with collection name in parameter.

Example in mongosh:

```
db.runCommand({collStats:"myCollection", scale:1000000})
```

Answer (score 3):

Per [DocumentDB official document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/mongo-apis.html),

| Command | 3.6 | 4.0 | 5.0 | Elastic cluster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $collStats | No | No | No | No |

So `$collStats` is not supported in DocumentDB as of now, no matter which version you are using.