# AWS Glue 4.0 failing when calling DynamicFrame.fromDF

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue, aws-documentdb

I'm trying to convert a Spark data frame in Python 3.10 into a dynamic frame using Glue's fromDF method
`from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame`
`DynamicFrame.fromDF(frame, glue_context, "node")`

But this throws an error on CloudWatch saying `com.mongodb.spark.sql.connector.exceptions.MongoSparkException: Partitioning failed.`

Inspecting the logs further, I found that under the hood Glue seems to be using `$collStats` somewhere, which is not supported by AWS DocumentDB. Note that this function worked when the job was Glue 2.0, but updating it to 4.0 has started causing this issue.
`com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 304: 'Aggregation stage not supported: '$collStats''`

I haven't really tried fixing this issue, because this seems to be happening under the hood, and I don't have access to the source code of Glue 4.0. The only thing is that this did not fail in Glue 2.0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Amazon DocumentDB error "Aggregation stage not supported: '$collStats'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77081441/amazon-documentdb-error-aggregation-stage-not-supported-collstats)

Comment: No, @ErmiyaEskandary, because this isn't something I'm doing, AWS Glue seems to be doing it under the hood when running `fromDF`. I'm aware that DocumentDB doesn't support $collStats, but this is arising within Glue's own method.

Comment: Aha, sorry I misread. Retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me is setting the partitioner in the batch read configuration for mongo-spark to be set to `SinglePartitionPartitioner`. Seems like the default was updated to use `SamplePartitioner` in Glue 4.0 and the newer mongo-spark connector versions which was causing the problem. [Refer the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/spark-connector/v10.1/batch-mode/batch-read-config)